# How can I duplicate a file x times in a different directory with terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, cp

I am trying to duplicate an image file to a different folder x times (100 times). How can I do this in the terminal?

I succeeded in duplicating in same folder, but I need to duplicate in another folder.

So far, I've tried this :

```
i=10; while((i++ < 100)); do cp index "index$i"; done
```

Please assist.

Comment: my file name index. but i try to duplicate image file axactly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just prepend the directory name before the filename(s):

```
i=0; while ((i++ < 100)); do cp index /destination/directory/"index$i"; done
```

Replace `/destination/directory` with the actual directory name.

Answer (score 4):

This assumes the file you want to copy is in the current working directory.
Replace `/path/to/destination` with the path to the real directory as required.
`index` should be replaced with the real filename if necessary:

```
for i in {1..100}; do echo cp -v -- index /path/to/destination/"index-$i"; done
```

Remove `echo` after testing, and repeat the command to actually copy the files

It would be better to make the numbers fixed-width for easier sorting, ie 001,002... 010 etc, so you could use `printf`:

```
for i in {1..100}; do printf -v new "index-%03d" "$i"; echo cp -v -- "index" /path/to/destination/"$new"; done
```

or more readably

```
for i in {1..100}; do
  printf -v new "index-%03d" "$i"
  echo cp -v -- "index" /path/to/destination/"$new"
done
```

Comment: Instead of `printf`, just use `{001..100}`.

Comment: @HTNW that's neat haha